# crc for download while using NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone

I have implemented downloading part using NSURLConnection.
Now I am trying to add one more function for CRC check. 
I read some basic concepts through wikipedia.
But I am bit confused how to start off.
Can anyone give me hint for this? Thank you

btw.. I am not trying to design the whole crc part by myself.

Comment: You do know that this isn't necessary, right? See comments below.

Answer (score 1):

zlib, which is included with iOS, includes a crc32() function:

```
uLong crc = crc32(0L, Z_NULL, 0);
crc = crc32(crc, [self bytes], (uInt)[self length]);
return crc;
```

Note that as Snips comments below, CRCs are built into TCP/IP. There are, of course, other reasons you might to do a CRC on iOS… but a basic check for packet integrity probably isn't one of them.

Comment: Just wondering... is it really necessary to add a crc at this level - shouldn't the lower layers of the TCP/IP take care of ensuring the data is delivered complete and without corruption?

Comment: Yes, TCP/IP has built-in 32bit CRC detection at the hardware level.

Comment: So I'm not going mad :-)  OP take note.

Comment: Why wondering? This might be simple checking if you get exactly that data what you need. You can save CRCs only in device, instead saving whole data.

Comment: Yeah, there's other reasons to do a CRC. But pointing out that packet integrity isn't one of them is a good point. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to implement simple crc by yourself. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_checksum_algorithms) can help.

For example adopted BSD 16-bit crc algorithm:

```
- (NSInteger)getBSDcrc:(NSData*)data {
    NSUInteger lendth = [data length];
    char *byte = (char*)[data bytes];
    NSInteger crc = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        crc = (crc >> 1) + ((crc & 1) << 15);
        crc += byte[i];
        crc &= 0xffff;
    }
    return crc;
}
```